# PHP mssql_connect() to Azure Database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, azure

I try to set connection with my site and mssql database. I can connect to database, but i can't execute SQL queries. My code is

```
$connection = mssql_connect('jass8l1.database.windows.net', 'username', 'password');
        if (!$connection){
            print_r(mssql_get_last_message());
        }else{

            $res= mssql_query('SELECT * FROM [my_database].[dbo].[table]', $connection);
            print_r(mssql_get_last_message());
            $row = mssql_fetch_array($res);

            echo $row[0];

        }
```

This code shows error

```
Reference to database and/or server name in 'my_database.dbo.table' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

But when I execute this query online, link MANAGE URL, this error does not occur.
How can I solve this problem? Maybe I need some additional driver is for PHP?

Comment: Did you try `SELECT * FROM table` without the fully-qualified table name?

Comment: Yes, if i try `SELECT * FROM table` , I get
`Invalid object name 'table'.`

Comment: https://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/php-connect-azure-db

Answer (score 3):

The error message cannot be more descriptive than it is!

You simply cannot use the 4-word-notation (i.e. [DB_NAME].[SCHEMA].[TABLE_NAME].[COLUMN]. With SQL Azure you shall always use the 3-word notation (i.e. [SCHEMA].[TABLE].[COLUMN]).

Something more for SQL Azure is that you have to explicitly set Database in your connection. You can **not** do `USE [DB_NAME]` in SQL Azure.

When using SQL Azure with PHP I recommend that you go through the [How to: Connect to Windows Azure SQL Database from PHP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394110.aspx).

You have to alter your connection to something like:

```
  $serverName = "tcp:ProvideServerName.database.windows.net,1433";
   $userName = 'ProvideUserName@ProvideServerName';
   $userPassword = 'ProvidePassword';
   $dbName = "TestDB";
   $table = "tablePHP";

   $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$dbName, "UID"=>$userName, "PWD"=>$userPassword, "MultipleActiveResultSets"=>true);

   sqlsrv_configure('WarningsReturnAsErrors', 0);
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
   if($conn === false)
   {
     FatalError("Failed to connect...");
   }
```

Also, it is strongly recommended to use Microsoft's MS SQL driver and not the standard PHP provided MSSQL (also referred in the How To).