# MS SQL Server Azure - PHP msssql_connect() connect to different database than master

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, php-mssql

I am restricted to use only PHP mssql module to use with
MS Azure SQL Server.

I am able to maintain connection by adding:
~/.freetds.conf:

```
[aftermath]
    database = mydatabase
    host = myhostname.database.windows.net
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
```

My code in PHP

```
$myServer = "aftermath"
$myUser = username@hostname
$myPass = obviously_my_pass

$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
```

But when I check which database is selected it returns:

```
 master
```

instead of my desired database which is specified in my freetds.conf file

Module sqlsrv is not installed on my hosting and I do not have rights to install it.

Can you tell me how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mssql\_connect() to Azure Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249696/php-mssql-connect-to-azure-database)

Comment: Answer presented in that topic is using sqlsrv function from module not installed on my hosting. I am unable to use it

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452262/how-to-query-in-a-specific-database-on-azure

Comment: sqlsrv is deprecated, try odbc: https://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/php-connect-azure-db